# What compilers are used in game development?

Tags: c++, c

I was kinda wondering *what **compilers** are used in game development*, since the **game development industry** always tries to squeeze every inch of performance out their software, using, among other, (*sometimes very aggresive*) compiler optimizations and the big boys in compiler technology (**[llvm](http://llvm.org), [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org)**), that excel in such kind optimizations are out of the game in the `*Windows operating System*`.

Comment: llvm is not a compiler, you mean clang I guess ;)

Comment: @MaikSemder LLVM is a compiler, or maybe a (great) percentage of what would be considered a compiler. It's the backend generator. `Clang` is the **frontend** for `C, C++, Obj-C`

Comment: A port of GCC is part of [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: @Asakeron Which (to my knowledge, could be wrong though) is nowhere near as good as vanilla `gcc`

Comment: And thus the non-constructive-ness of the answer is revealed in the answers. This is just generating a list...

Comment: @NlightNFotis you might be right, but then [llvm.org](http://llvm.org/) would be wrong: **Clang is an "LLVM native" C/C++/Objective-C compiler**

Comment: @MaikSemder If you actually did press on the link to the clang website (here it is, case you missed it http://clang.llvm.org/) you would see that it very clearly states `The goal of the Clang project is to create a new C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ **front-end** for the LLVM compiler.`

Comment: *of the question. Doh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update for November 2018**

LLVM/Clang is the primary (or only) compiler for many gaming platforms these days. iOS, Android, PlayStation 4, MacOS/OSX, and Nintendo Switch all use Clang as their default native compiler.

XBox One is only supported by Microsoft's compiler, and their compiler is also still the most commonly used for Windows.

A handful of legacy or less mainstream platforms use other compilers, like 3DS' use of Green Hills' compiler.

GCC may sometimes see use on Linux (server) builds due to it being the default C++ compiler on most major Linux distributions.

Some studios may use specialized optimizing compilers like ICC for supported platforms, but most do not. This is partly because no mainstream client gaming platform besides PC uses Intel processors

**Original circa 2012**

There's a few misconceptions in your question.  First, games don't really new any kind of special super-optimizing compiler.  We've long since hit the point where the hardware is beefy enough, common compilers optimize well enough, and games are complex enough that micro-optimizing instructions has little value outside of a few specialized loops.  Also, while I love LLVM, it is hardly a "big boy" in the compiler space, and it generally has the worst optimizations of all the major compilers (for now), and hence it is not really used outside of Apple's newer dev environments.

Microsoft Visual C++ is the primary compiler for Windows and XBox.  A few places use Intel's ICC for Windows, but that's rare.

Modified ancient crusty versions of GCC provided by the hardware vendor are used for all the non-Microsoft consoles.

Apple's ancient modified GCC is used for iOS, and OSX.  It is being phased for the LLVM-based Clang.  A more modern version of GCC is used for Android.

Linux isn't much of a gaming platform, but the few commercial games out there for it are compiled with a fairly recent GCC usually.

Comment: Finally a great answer to my question. However I don't agree with your statement that `llvm` is not a big boy. While I am not by any means a `llvm` fanboy, you have to admit that **apple** and `FreeBSD` making it a default compiler for their systems, `debian` being enthusiastic about it, and the sole fact that `gcc` are changing their implementation language to `C++` (LLVM's implementation language) should say something about LLVM. At the very least, it's applying some pressure on GCC.

Comment: You mention Linux with a note that it "isn't much of a gaming platform" but Mac without, really?

Comment: @NlightNFotis: LLVM is great.  It's still not a major compiler in use by anyone but a handful of early adopters (and fringe OSes that have eschewed GCC since the move to GPLv3 and have otherwise been stuck on ancient GPLv2 releases), and is not yet a leader in the industry, especially for people who care about optimization quality.  That's all I meant.

Comment: @Mr.Beast: Linux has a small fraction as many commercial games as OSX.  OSX isn't exactly hot, but at least you can buy new AAA games for it today (look at the Steam Linux vs Steam OSX catalogs, for example).

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch Steam for Linux is still in Beta, of course there aren't that many games on it yet. It's true that Linux hasn't received much love from AAA developers yet (which is likely to change with the support of Steam, though). However, for Indie games there is not so much difference in the level of support for Mac and Linux, as the statistics on Desura show: http://www.desura.com/games/browse/ 900 games for Windows, 290 games for Mac and 230 games for Linux.

Comment: _Linux isn't much of a gaming platform_, Ah, how times have changed!

Comment: @Shahbaz They haven't. People don't really play games on Linux.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch What about Intel's compiler? I've heard it reigns supreme in performance and optimizations. Do major game studios use icc for game development compilation? It's mostly for Intel CPUs only though and compilation times are generally higher.

Comment: @Nik-Lz: I'm sure some game companies use it, but not a significant number (that I know of). ICC doesn't support ARM (99% of mobile) and doesn't support the current-gen gaming console AMD APUs (nor the PPC consoles out when this answer was written). ICC is mostly relevant for scientific/server folks who are explicitly targeting Xeon systems. Note also that in the half-decade since this answer was originally written, pretty much every gaming platform moved to a Clang/LLVM-based compiler by default, aside from Windows and XBox.

Comment: @Nik-Lz, 1. the percentage of Linux gamers among Linux desktop users vs the percentage of Windows gamers among Windows desktop users is really not that different. So people have the same chance of playing games whether they are on Linux or Windows. 2. I wasn't talking about people at all, but "Linux as a gaming platform". Linux was a target on Steam only since 2013 and there are already 4000~5000 games supporting it. Then there is Valve's Proton (a fork of wine) to try to get any windows game on steam to run on Linux. So as a "platform", it's in pretty good shape for gaming.

Comment: @Shahbaz Sure Linux has the potential. But I just wonder why developers even bother with it. Linux isn't really meant for that. Do ordinary, typical users use Linux? No. And why would they? Why would they want to mess with command line staff and whatnot. Will your typical admin play games on Linux after a hard day's work? When there is Windows and of course consoles. I personally believe support of games on linux comes mostly due to OpenGL being cross platform. So besides that, there's not much more to develop in order to support any potential Linux gamers.

Comment: @Shahbaz Why have both DirectX and OpenGL support? It's just currently impossible to universally support every architecture. And there's just no need either. Focus on delivering a quality product on a target platform, than quantity, ie. a game supported by every single computing device out there. And especially not Linux! If game developers focus on linux as a gaming platform then I believe they are confused and that will certainly backfire in the long (or short) run. That is my opinion.

Comment: _Do ordinary, typical users use Linux? No._ So that's not true. My wife installs Ubuntu for my (extremely non-technical) father-in-law, because all he does is browse the internet, and she doesn't have to worry about him screwing anything up (no root password) or catch a virus. See https://www.gamingonlinux.com/ for 
a glimpse of ordinary people playing games on Linux.

Comment: _Why would they want to mess with command line staff and whatnot. Will your typical admin..._, it looks like you haven't touched Linux in ten years. No command line stuff is necessary any more, and the users are not admins. In fact, having switched over to Linux about 5 years ago, I tend to end up with more stuff breaking on windows when I encounter one than I experience with Linux. As a bonus point, the computer doesn't beg for a restart every other day.\

Comment: _I personally believe support of games on linux comes mostly due to OpenGL being cross platform._ Not at all. OpenGL stagnated for a few years when d3d10 came out, a fact that turned into a widespread propaganda which to this date has left the impression that "opengl is slow" in the mind of graphics programmer. What I'm saying is that no one (other than major engines) is developing OpenGL anymore. Valve's initiative which turned into Vulkan (and because of which (i.e. competition) d3d12 came out) was specifically to bring in a new cross-platform API that doesn't have a negative image.

Comment: _If game developers focus on linux as a gaming platform then I believe they are confused and that will certainly backfire in the long (or short) run._ They are not confused, many things are in effect that create a push for Linux gaming. The most public one is Valve, whose effort (SteamOS) started as a way to stop microsoft from forcing all software (and therefore profit) to go through their store. There are other companies whose plans I cannot reveal due to NDA, but I can assure you even more (and bigger) companies are doing Linux support for their games.

Comment: In summary, I think some of your information is outdated (no harm, everyone's information is outdated unless they actively keep it up-to-date). So to quote my original comment summarizing all the above regarding how things are not what they used to be: _Ah, how times have changed!_

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion/arguments. Take this to chat. :)

Answer (score 5):

On windows, most people use visual studio and its build tools. Xbox 360 uses it as well. On just about everything else, some version of GCC is typically used. (PS3 & Nintendo consoles use a customized version of GCC)

Comment: I am sorry to break the news for you, but `Visual Studio` is not a **compiler**. It's an **IDE**.

Comment: Dude, MSBuild is a build tool for **managed applications**, that is applications running on `.Net framework`. At least the games that I am speaking of (modern **AAA** titles) don't run on a managed environment for a lot of reasons.

Comment: @NightNFotis Visual Studio's compiler is called **CL**.

Comment: you know what I am referring to

Comment: I think it's extremely clear that CobaltHex means Visual Studio as a suite, including the compiler. Strange of you to respond with 'have to break the news for you' when someone gives fair answer to your question even if it would've been wrong. You're also wrong about MSBuild, which is not a tool just for managed applications, it's the build system like `make` is for c/c++.

Comment: @RoyT. First of all you are looking at the edited answer. The original answer read "**most people use visual studio**". I am sorry, but when someone answers a question about **compilers**, I won't accept such a vague answer. It would as well read **"most people use eclipse"**. Would you take **eclipse** as a compiler? Your call. Now regarding `MSBuild` I am sorry and I apologise If I make a mistake, I am more of an open source developer and not really into MS products, however, I **didn't** really see anywhere stating that `MSBuild` builds everything, including **non** managed applications.

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293626.aspx):

"You can use the MSBuild tool to build a Visual C++ application from the command prompt. The build process is controlled by the information in a project file (.vcxproj) that you can create and edit. The project file specifies build options based on build stages, conditions, and events."

Comment: @Asakeron Read what you wrote "a **VISUAL** C++ application". `Visual` --> runs on a managed environment (`.NET framework`)

Comment: It's possible to write unmanaged code in Visual C++.

Comment: Visual C++ is the name of the program. You can write using .net or you can not. (Including the visual designer)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler that comes with Visual Studio / C++.

I don't program for a game development company, just a boring business software developer. Our target platform is Microsoft, and we use Visual Studio 2010 for C++ and C# .Net.

Comment: I asked specifically for games, because games have very different needs than most of the other categories of software.

Comment: Yes, I can read. Why would you use a different compiler for Windows than the industry standard for Windows platforms?

Comment: I could think of a myriad of reasons. First and foremost is that the industry standard may suck at optimizations.

Comment: Sounds like you already know everything you need to know champ.

Comment: @NlightNFotis what exactly do you think is different in a game from an optimizing-compiler p.o.v? I can tell you that I know first hand that some recent Ubisoft titles are compiled using VS2008's C++ compiler.

Comment: @RoyT. I really don't know dude. That's why I asked in the first place.